# Send a direct message on private message to welcome new users who join the server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to get the bot to send a direct/private message to new users that join the server. It is able to post a welcome message on a channel but it keeps throwing errors for direct messages.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client ();

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
       member.guild.defaultChannel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`);
       console.log(`${member.user.username} has joined`);
});

bot.login('TOKEN_HERE');
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I was trying a few ways but most of them give me a function error. I was using this last: member.sendMessage(message.author, "Hello!"); and that gives a not defined error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Member` object has a send method just like channels.

**Note** sendMessage is deprecated

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client ();

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
   member.send("Welcome to the server!");
});

bot.login('TOKEN_HERE');
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python one can run a script as follows ([Source](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#welcoming-new-members))

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord server!'
    )

client.run(TOKEN)
```

`on_member_join()` handles the event of a new member joining a guild.

In this example it uses `member.create_dm()` to create a direct message channel. Then, uses that channel to `.send()` a direct message to that new member.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  member.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`);
});
```

Simply add that or if you want to be more customized or use the embed

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('color number')
    .setTitle('your welcome message')
    .setDescription(`yourwelcome message, ${member}!`)
    .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
    .addFields(
      { name: 'User:', value: `${member.user.tag}`, inline: true },
      { name: 'ID:', value: `${member.user.id}`, inline: true },
      { name: 'Joined at:', value: `${member.joinedAt}`, inline: true },
    )   
  member.send(embed);
})
```